# Javascript toString() method

Tags: javascript, methods, tostring

Say `hol` is a `Date()` object.

Why is `hol.toString()` useful or helpful?
isn't it the same as just writing/outputting `hol`?

also other related methods such as

```
toDateString()
toTimeString()
```

Comment: I am not too much into javascript, but thats something like java i guess. When you say Hol its an object of type date. So there will be many functions of date available using that object(toDateString and toTimeString being two of those), whereas once you convert them to string you can then just do string manipulation as now its a string object

Answer (score 2):

Doing something like `alert("The time is now: " + hol);` is actually implicitly calling `alert("The time is now: " + hol.toString());`

Also, from the Mozilla Developer Network [[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString)] [[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toTimeString)]:

```
var d = new Date(1993, 6, 28, 14, 39, 7);
println(d.toString()); // prints Wed Jul 28 1993 14:39:07 GMT-0600 (PDT)
println(d.toDateString()); // prints Wed Jul 28 1993
println(d.toTimeString()); // prints 14:39:07 GMT-0600 (PDT)
```

So the additional methods are providing for different predefined formats.

Note also as documented for both the `toDateString` and `toTimeString` methods:

> The toDateString/toTimeString method is especially useful because
>   compliant engines implementing ECMA-262 may differ in the string
>   obtained from toString for Date objects, as the format is
>   implementation-dependent and simple string slicing approaches may not
>   produce consistent results across multiple engines.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_date.asp) shows that `toString()` is called whenever a `Date()` object needs to be displayed as a string, so you don't need to call it yourself.

Also, if you want to display a `Date()` object, you should use a method like the ones you mentioned (`toDateString()`,`toTimeString()`), but when I coded a script that displays the date, I didn't use either of those methods. I used the `getWhatever()` methods of the `Date()` object. This gives you a little more control over what you want to display.

Unless you don't want to program it yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually document.write ( guess that is what you mean by `writing` ) invokes 'toString' to convert any Object to String. That is the function in which we can define how the string representation of the object should be. If that function is not defined string equivalent of the object will not be printed.

e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/8bP37/

Also try this

```
Date.prototype.toString = null;
document.write(new Date());
```

You can see the time value getting displayed.

Comment: It is used by more than `document.write`. The reason for this particular behavior is because the internal function [`ToString`](http://es5.github.com/#x9.8) uses `ToPrimitive`, which down the line will try to use a callable `toString` method of the object -- or a callable `valueOf` if `toString` is not available. This is why when you get rid of `Date#toString` (as in your example), it ends up displaying the time as a UNIX timestamp: that is the result of `Date#valueOf`.